# How to generate multiple depth lists of ranges in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

Suppose you have a label which increments in multiple spots:

For example, `1-A-1`.
Suppose the third spot can increment up to 10 times (`1-A-10`), after which, `A` will become `B`: `1-B-1`.

Then, this process repeats until `1-Z-10`, and after that is incremented, you have `2-A-1`.

How can I write a generic function that will generate a list which has all combinations from `1-A-1` to `10-Z-10`?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @trotta I would, but I have generalized this problem for the purpose of asking the question to the point where my code is not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use case for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
labels = itertools.product(range(1, 11), string.ascii_uppercase, range(1, 11))
# (1, 'A', 1) (1, 'A', 2) (1, 'A', 3) ...
```

`product(as, bs, cs, ds, ...)` creates a generator that produces values akin to a multiple-level-deep `for` loop:

```
for a in as:
    for b in bs:
        for c in cs:
            for d in ds:
                yield (a, b, c, d)
```

so to use this, you can either cast directly to list:

```
result = [f"{a}-{b}-{c}" for a, b, c in labels]
```

or loop over `labels`

```
for label in labels:
    a, b, c = label
    formatted = f"{a}-{b}-{c}"
    # do something with formatted
```

Comment: What if the argument is a variable number of ranges? I know what you said works for this specific example, but my program needs to be dynamic. Sometimes it will have one range, sometimes it will have 3 ranges, etc.

Comment: @Matthew try it. You'll find that `product` is variadic

Comment: What I meant was how do you pass a list of lists to a variadic function that expects only lists as arguments, but I found that you can use a preceding asterisk in the function argument to unpack the list of lists to lists.